# Switch to Google Maps on Android using Intent without cancelling navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, switch-statement

From my application, the user can select to be given driving directions to an incident.

I'm successfully launching Google Maps Navigation from my application using an Intent.

However, if the user switches back to my application, I have a button that they can use to quickly switch back to the map to check the navigation.

When I try to do this, it keeps prompting the user if they wish to cancel the current navigation, even though I'm just trying to switch to the application with no additional parameters/data.

Is it possible to just switch back to Google Maps from my application without interfering with what Google Maps is doing?

Comment: please provide your source code that youre talking about

Comment: If you are using the same intent, Google maps will handle that intent same as before, opening a new navigation to that point.  You must switch back to Google Maps with a new intent.